# Extracting matches from strings with lookaround in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have textual data (storytellings) and my aim is to extract certain words that are defined by a co-occurrence pattern, namely that they occur immediately prior to overlap, which is indicated by square brackets. The data are like this:

```
who <- c("Sue:", NA, "Carl:", "Sue:", NA, NA, NA, "Carl:", "Sue:","Carl:", "Sue:","Carl:")
story <- c("That’s like your grand:ma. did that with::=erm          ",
       "with Ju:ne (.) once or [ twice.]                        ",
       "                       [ Yeah. ]                        ",
       "And June wanted to go out and yo- your granny said (0.8)",
       "“make sure you're ba(hh)ck before midni(hh)ght.”        ",
       "[Mm.]                                                   ",
       "[There] she was (.) a ma(h)rried woman with a(h)-       ",
       "She’s a right wally.                                    ",
       "mm [kids  as well ]                                     ",
       "   [They    assume] an awful lot man¿                   ",
       "°°ye:ah,°°                                              ",
      "°°the elderly do.°°                                      ")
CAt <- data.frame(who, story)
```

Now, defining the pattern:

```
pattern <- "\\w.*\\s\\[[^]].*]"
```

and using grep():

```
grep(pattern, CAt$story, value = T)
[1] "with Ju:ne (.) once or [ twice.]                        "
[2] "mm [kids  as well ]                                     "
```

I get the two strings that *contain* the target matches but what I'm really after are the target words only, in this case the words "or" and "mm". This, to me, seems to call for positive lookahead. So I redefined the pattern thus:

```
pattern <- "\\w.*(?=\\s\\[[^]].*])"
```

which says something along the lines: "match the word iff you see a space followed by square brackets with some content on the right of that word". Now to extract only the exact matches, I normally use this code, which works fine as long as no lookaround is involved, but here it throws an error:

```
unlist(regmatches(CAt$story, gregexpr(pattern, CAt$story)))
Error in gregexpr(pattern, CAt$story) : 
invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

Why is this? And how can the exact matches be extracted?

Comment: Try adding `perl=TRUE` to [gregexpr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/microseq/versions/1.2.3/topics/gregexpr)

Comment: Thanks. I've also changed the pattern to really get only the one prior word: `pattern <- "\\w+(?=\\s\\[[^]].*])"`

Comment: You could omit the dot from the pattern as you want to repeat the negated character class and not the dot which will match any character `\w+(?=\s\[[^]]*])` See https://regex101.com/r/EJqCY7/1 Another option could be using a capturing group instead of a lookahead `(\w+)\s\[[^]]*]` See https://regex101.com/r/EJqCY7/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you could add `perl=TRUE` to gregexpr.

In your pattern `\w.*` will match a single word char followed by matching any char 0+ times.

This part `\[[^]].*]` will match `[`, then 1 char which is not `]` and then  `.*` which will match any char 0+ times followed by `]`.

You could update your pattern to repeating the word char and the character class itself instead.

```
\w+(?=\s\[[^]]*])
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `\s` Match single whitespace char
  - `\[[^]]*]` Match from opening`[` to closing `]` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EJqCY7/1)

Using doubled backslashes:

```
\\w+(?=\\s\\[[^]]*])
```

As an alternative you could use a capturing group instead of using a lookahead

```
(\w+)\s\[[^]]*]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EJqCY7/2)

Comment: Thanks. A follow-up question: Positive lookbehind does not work--Why? `pattern <- "(?<=\\[[^]]*]\\s)\\w+"
grep(pattern, CAt$story, perl = T)
Error in grep(pattern, CAt$story, perl = T) : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<=\[[^]]*]\s)\w+'
In addition: Warning message:
In grep(pattern, CAt$story, perl = T) : PCRE pattern compilation error
 'lookbehind assertion is not fixed length'
 at ')\w+'`

Comment: That is due to the quantifier `*` in the positive lookbehind `(?<=\[[^]]*]` which is not supported by the engine. See this page for more information about [Lookbehind: Fixed-Width / Constrained Width / Infinite Width](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width)